# Recorded sound file (ala google now, google keep) - RecognizerIntent/Listener

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, voice-recording

I have been developing an application that uses the recognizerIntent to get voice input. However, since jelly bean was launched, I have not been able to get the actual sound file from my voice input.

In the recognitionListener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html) there is a method called onBufferReceived. However, there are no promises that this method will be called, and when I implemented it, it never got called. Is there any way to force this method to execute or what is the "best-practice"-approach to gather the sound file that the recognizerIntent analyzes?

It should be possible since both google now can do it with the voice-command "note-to-self", and Google Keep:s voice-notes does the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to force it. It clearly depends on the recognition service implementation. If Google decides to not call `onBufferReceived` then there is no way to get the actual data that is used. Note that the mentioned Google apps don't use the (public) Intent / Service API to access the speech recognition but seem to use a private API within the apps (the speech recognition might be bundled within their apps).