# How can I include file as well as the recognized voice in Android?

Tags: android, file, audio, voice-recognition, google-now

I have an app where I want to send both the recognized text as well as the sound it listens from. The problem is that I can't seem to get it to work. Seems like some after JellyBean issue. Both Google Now "note to self" and Google keep uses this, so it should work....

In [recognitionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html)  there is a method called onBufferReceived. The problem is that I can't get it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547438/recorded-sound-file-ala-google-now-google-keep-recognizerintent-listener

Comment: No answer there either, seems like there is no answer for this yet.